# Fetching Max(id) in a list-partitioned table takes > 2 min to fetch data

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have a table which is partitioned by a small int field.

The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    sent         BIGINT   NOT NULL, 
    received     BIGINT   NOT NULL,
    id           BIGINT   NOT NULL,
    property     SMALLINT NOT NULL ) PARTITION BY LIST (property);
```

And I am trying this:

```
 SELECT max(id) FROM t where property = ANY (ARRAY[0,1,2])
```

This query takes a very long time to fetch the results.

And Analyze shows:

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=127530081.31..127530081.32 rows=1 width=4)  
->  Gather  (cost=127530081.09..127530081.30 rows=2 width=4)
        Workers Planned: 2
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=127529081.09..127529081.10 rows=1 width=4)
              ->  Parallel Append  (cost=0.00..121341655.08 rows=2474970404 width=4)
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on t_0  (cost=0.00..66038474.72 rows=1463937981 width=4)
                          Filter: ((property = 0) OR (property = 1))
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on t_1  (cost=0.00..42928328.34 rows=1011032423 width=4)
                          Filter: ((property = 0) OR (property = 1))
```

But I get a very quick response when I use UNION query to do the same.

```
 SELECT max(max) 
 FROM (
   SELECT max(id) FROM t WHERE property = 1 
   UNION 
   SELECT max(id) FROM transfer where property = 2 
   UNION 
   SELECT max(id) FROM t where property = 3 
 ) as t1
```

How can this behaviour be explained?

Comment: I have a milti-column index on (property, sent, id)

Comment: What version of postgres?  Do you see any difference if you use `property IN (0, 1, 2)` instead of `property = ANY(ARRAY[0,1, 2])`?

Comment: @Jeremy I don't see any major difference if I use property IN (0,1,2) . I am using PostgreSQL 11.4 version on linux